# Referencing indices of a sorted array to the old array (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Given some randomly arranged array of day strings:

```
var days = ['Tues', 'Thur', 'Mon', 'Wed']
```

with `days[0] = 'Tues'`, `days[1] = 'Thurs'`, etc. After sorting, we get

```
sortedDays = ['Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thur']
```

However, I'd like to reference the indices of the newly-sorted array to the old array, i.e., the old array has indices (0, 1, 2, 3) while the new array has indices (2, 0, 3, 1).

I have no idea on how to achieve this.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by you'd like to reference the indices? Do you simply want to know the order of items in the second array with regard to the original?

Comment: Yeap, I'd just like to know how the indices changed after the sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the sorted indexes you can start with an array from [0...n] and then sort that array based on the sort order of the days.

For example:

```js
// Determines how we will we sort the days:
const sortDays = {
    Mon:  0,
    Tues: 1, 
    Wed:  2,
    Thur: 3,
    Fri:  4,
    Sat:  5,
    Sun:  6
}

const days = ['Tues', 'Thur', 'Mon', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Sun', 'Mon'];
// plain indices
let index = Array.from(days, (_,i) => i)
index.sort((a, b) => sortDays[days[a]] - sortDays[days[b]])

// now indices are sorted according to days sort order
console.log("indices: ", index.join(','))

// you can use the index to sort days:
sortedDays = index.map(i => days[i])
console.log("sorted days:", sortedDays.join(','))
```

This has the advantage of giving you the correct indices even when you have duplicates in the original list.

Answer (score 2):

`Array.prototype.indexOf()` would be what you need here to find the position (index) of an element within an array. Simply call `.indexOf()` on every element in your `sortedDays` array.

```js
const days = ['Tues', 'Thur', 'Mon', 'Wed'];
const sortedDays = ['Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thur'];
const sortedDaysIndices = sortedDays.map(day => days.indexOf(day));
console.log(sortedDaysIndices);
```

Comment: This is a little problematic if there are duplicate entries since it will give the same index for both. It's not clear in the OP's question is that's an issue of not.

Comment: Fair point! But if there are duplicates how do you know which one of the duplicate in the sorted array would reference which index in the original array?

Comment: Right, it may not matter at all since the dupes are not distinct in any way.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var days = ['Tues', 'Thur', 'Mon', 'Wed'];

var sortedDays = ['Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thur'];

var indexMapping = {}
days.forEach((item, index)=> (indexMapping[item] = { 
    oldIndex: index  , newIndex: sortedDays.indexOf(item)}
 )
)

console.log(indexMapping)
```